# How shallow prop compare works for connected components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

As per the documentation of redux, reducer always gives a new copy of state.
In a connected component react-redux does a shallow comparison of the attributes mentioned in `mapStateToProps`(old vs new props).

My confusion is, since redux always provides a new copy of state, the shallow comparison done by react-redux should always give false and the component should always rerender. But this does not happen.

Can someone explain what I am missing?

I am considering all the attributes read in mapStateToProp are objects.

Comment: Can you share your `mapStateToProps`? This largely depends on it. Maybe you are using something like `reselect` (which handle cache)?

Comment: const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    response: state.simpleReducer.result,
});


the 'result' is an array and  i have not used reselect. Its a pretty basic redux app.

My confusion is, in this app i am changing some other part of state through some action. and if redux gvies me a new copy of state.(where the value of result array is unchanged)
So when the shallow comparison at component level happens, won't the array from old and new store point to different locations leading to shallow comparison fail and rerender ?

Comment: Are you using combineReducers? can you share your connected component?

Comment: Yes I am using combineReducers. There is only one reducer though. Which I am passing in combineReducer

Comment: What your reducer looks like? Are you returning a new array for results?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question by any chance? I spent hours reading through the redux and react-redux documentation trying figure it out with no success whatsoever. My app actually behaves as you describe - it doesn't update if values are primitive and updated with every action for objects (which makes total sense as they always have new refs).

Comment: I added a new answer for the original question.

Answer (score 0):

We both agree that `mapStateToProps` Will Not Run if the Store State is the Same. So as redux docs are:

> The wrapper component generated by connect subscribes to the Redux
>   store. Every time an action is dispatched, it calls `store.getState()`
>   and checks to see if `lastState === currentState`. If the two state
>   values are identical by reference, then it will not re-run your
>   `mapStateToProps` function, because it assumes that the rest of the
>   store state hasn't changed either.

The answer for 
[Why isn't my component re-rendering, or my mapStateToProps running?](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-isn-t-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running) can describe your case, as you have might accidentally mutated your state directly.

And since you are using 'combineReducers' (which is great though) there is one more "Gotcha":

> `combineReducers` utility function tries to optimize state updates. If
>   none of the slice reducers returned a new value, then combineReducers
>   returns the old state object instead of a new one. This means that
>   mutation in a reducer can lead to the root state object not being
>   updated, and thus the UI won't re-render.

Answer (score 0):

As long as a sub reducer isn't mutated, it stays referentially same regardless of the root state is a new object or not, so that connect's shallow comparison on that part of reducer always return true. Hence, no re-render happens on the components that depend on that particular state.

```
const subReducerState = { innerProp: 3 };

const prevRootState = { subReducerState: subReducerState };

const nextRootState = { subReducerState: subReducerState };

prevRootState.subReducerState === nextRootState.subReducerState // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux does not give you a new copy always. It's programmers job to make sure it does when it really should by being careful on the followings:

- Is your reducer actually changing any state **AND** returning a new object **immutably** (see below)? If not, your redux reducer will simply return the old object, thus no re-rendering. You might be returning the original array by mistake.

> - Copying objects using functions like `Object.assign()` or `_.extend()`,
>   and array functions such as `slice()` and `concat()`.
> - The array spread operator in ES6, and the similar object spread operator that is
>   proposed for a future version of JavaScript.
> - Utility libraries that wrap immutable update logic into simpler functions

- Similarly, if you're using `combineReducer()`, make sure all of your reducers that makes up the combined reducer are actually returning a new object.
- Are you doing any mutation on the old state? if you do, then those will not cause a new object to be returned on their own. You need to return a **NEW** object **WITH** desired changes applied as described above. Never mutate the old state, as it will be used in comparison with the new state later.
- If you have nested objects (ex: `main.subpart.nanopart`) and if you made a change in a nested object in your reducer, you need to return new object for it **AND** for **ALL** of it's parents.  For example: any change in `nanopart` should return new object for each of `nanopart`, `subpart` and `main`. [See here for a visual describing it](http://arqex.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/trees.png)
- If your reducer is returning the old state for unhandled actions, which is normally the case, you might not be handling the actions inside your reducers correctly and causing the old object to be returned from the `default` branch for unhandled actions.
- Your reducer should be pure: given the inputs, the output should be same (**deterministic pure calculation**). So, you should NOT use non-deterministic elements like utilizing `Date.now()`, `Math.random()`. Also you should not cause side-effects like API calls or routing transmissions. Keep the reducer to pure calculations made on old state to return the new state as a new object. Read [basics of reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) here

React-Redux may also contribute to the problem

- The views decorated with `connect()` calls [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and that only considers props for changes. If your view is dependent on global state or its parent components ([see React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)), then your component is not going to get re-rendered based on changes in global state or parent component. This can be caused by your 3rd party libraries. You need to pass changes through props OR indicate that your component is NOT pure (not advised as it gets slower).

  export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
  null,
  {
  pure: false
  }
  )(YourApp)
- Also make sure

> you either bind action creators with the `mapDispatchToProps`
> argument to `connect()` or with the `bindActionCreators()` method, or that
> you manually call `dispatch()`. Just calling your
> `MyActionCreators.addTodo()` function won’t work because it just returns
> an action, but does not dispatch it

Check these troubleshooting pages which explains these in more details:

https://redux.js.org/troubleshooting

https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-isn-t-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running

https://react-redux.js.org/troubleshooting